# GPU memory usage accumulating when calling function even though tensor isn't stored

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu

Hey I have a probably very simple question, but I couldn't find answers to it when searching. I've been testing how PyTorch manages GPU memory, and found a memory leak that I am not sure how to resolve. Consider this piece of code

```
a = torch.randn(1000000,10)
a = a.to(device=device) #device here is is my GPU
b = torch.randn(1000000,10)
b = b.to(device= device)

def sum2(c,d):
    return c+d
```

Now the GPU's memory usage as measured by `nvidia-smi` and `torch.cuda.memory_allocated()` increases by `80 MiB` (`40 MiB` each for a and b)

Now if I were to repeatedly call  `sum2(a,b)`, without storing the result (I am doing this in a jupyter notebook, not sure if that is relevant), the GPU memory usage keeps increasing by `40 MiB` with every call, indicating that the result somehow is stored in GPU even though the result tensor isn't really referenced and the result is "lost".

This behavior persists even when I wrap the `return c+d` in a `with torch.no_grad():`

Any ideas what is going on here and how to make sure that memory doesn't baloon up in this way?

Comment: It's python.  Did you try using `del` ?  `w = sum2(a,b)`,  `del w`   https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-delete-a-tensor-in-gpu-to-free-up-memory/48879/9

Comment: Hey, I am not storing sum2(a,b) in a variable, just calling it.

Comment: Perhaps you might want to study the link I provided. I expect the GPU memory management under python to be "pythonic". GPU memory allocations will probably have reference counts, and when their reference counts go to zero, they will be added to a pile for garbage collection.  garbage collection and eventual free-ing of the memory may not happen right away, but having the memory allocations in the garbage pile means they shouldn't interfere with new allocations. The allocator will free them on-demand if needed. If its a problem, why not assign to a variable?  Then you can explicitly delete it.

Comment: and as indicated in the link, calling `torch.cuda.empty_cache()` might be worth a try

Comment: If I recall correctly, pytorch tends to hold onto GPU resources for a while even after the GC frees the CPU structure. It does this because allocating GPU memory is expensive and the devs assume you will probably need more later so why not hold onto it. You can test if this is the case by calling `torch.cuda.empty_cache()` between calls to `sum2` and check if your memory usage stabilizes.The real question is why memory increases and not reused? Perhaps a case of memory fragmentation cause by whatever machanism pytorch uses to allocate GPU memory?

Comment: I tried calling torch.cuda.empty_cache() however that doesn't free up the memory that accumulated from the function calls, only freed up the OS managed memory (nividia-smi tracked) for a and b when I did del a,b Edit: added 'OS' part

Comment: Saying " I am not storing sum2(a,b), just calling it" makes no sense. The functions creates a new object and returns it at the scope you called it from. From there you are at the mercy of the Python memory and object management rules. The obvious solution is to pass a mutable object to hold the result of the call. Don't lazily create a new object. Also, give this is all Python and PyTorch semantics, I have removed the CUDA tag -- you have no CUDA programming question and it is no relevant to the behaviour of PyTorch in this case